# timer doesn't work in cocoa/mac OS in Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstimer

I cant see why this time doesnt update. Been looking the entire day. I don't know if is something related to being my first MacOs project, and there's maybe something that's escaping me, but I'd love some help.

```
import Cocoa

class TextViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var text: NSScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var dreadline: NSTextField!

var seconds: Int = 60
var timer: Timer?

var theWork = Dreadline(email: "", worktime: 0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(seconds)

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
        print(self.seconds)
        self.updateTimer()
    } // this is the timer that doesn't work no matter what I try :(
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    if seconds < 1 {
        timer?.invalidate()
    } else {
        seconds -= 1     //This will decrement(count down)the seconds.
        dreadline.stringValue = "Dreadline: " + timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds)) //This will update the label.
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it's declared as a local variable in the `viewDidLoad`, it's probable that it's been dereferenced when `viewDidLoad` exist, thereby canceling it

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, a "scheduled" timer is retained by the run loop.

Comment: @JoshCaswell So it's the call back that's dereferenced?

Comment: No, that's retained by the timer.

Answer (score 2):

A very common mistake: You are creating a *local* timer which is not the same as the declared property.

Replace

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    print(self.seconds)
    self.updateTimer()
} // this is the timer that doesn't work no matter what I try :(
```

with

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    print(self.seconds)
    self.updateTimer()
} // this is the timer that doesn't work no matter what I try :(
```

The `self` before `timer` is actually not mandatory.

And set the timer to `nil` after invalidation to avoid a retain cycle

```
if seconds < 1 {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

---

On the other hand you **can** use the *local* timer by **deleting** the property and change the code to

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    print(self.seconds)
    self.updateTimer(timer)
} 

func updateTimer(_ timer : Timer) {
    if seconds < 1 {
        timer.invalidate()
    } else {
        seconds -= 1     //This will decrement(count down)the seconds.
        dreadline.stringValue = "Dreadline: " + timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds)) //This will update the label.
    }
}
```

Comment: While the OP does need to remove `let`, is it really true that the problem is due to the local variable? A scheduled timer is retained by the runloop so the timer should still work.

Comment: Use `weak self` or you will have a retain cycle with your first method.

Comment: @HowardLi Thanks, I edited the answer to suggest an alternative

Comment: @Howard There is no retain cycle in `Timer` clouser, no need to use `weak self` in this case.